# How do EJB containers dynamically load/unload EJBs?

Tags: java, memory, static, ejb, containers

Containers like WebSphere can dynamically load/reload EJBs.  How to they clear resources and memory held by any static classes in the EJB ecosystem so that static cruft doesnt accumulate as operators load and reload modules?

Answer (score 0):

Class loaders and their classes can be garbage-collected just like any other Java objects. Once an application being undeployed is stopped and all of its objects are garbage collected, the container throws away the class loader, and all the class information becomes eligible.